# How do I tell if the input has used duplicate letters?

Tags: python

```
list = [ "A", "B" ,"C","T"]
```

I want to make a word from letters in a string. If the user inputs "cat" then that's correct, but if it's "CATT" then that's wrong. How would I detect that? The computer just sees if "A,B,C,T" is used but not how many times.

Comment: Are you aware of the `count()` method? You could use that to make sure the count of each character in the input matches the count of the output. Does that help?

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of marked question? I see this as checking a string to see if the characters from a list is repeated. Linked question is about seeing if a list has duplicate elements in itself.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could use `len(word)` to get the length of the word, right?

Also, a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is a container of unique values. That is, you can’t have the same value in a set more than once.

You can also pass a string into a set to fill the set with unique characters in the string.

Finally, you can take `len(set)` to get the number of unique items in the set.

So, if you add that all together:

```
>>> word = “CATT”
>>> len(word)
4
>>> my_set = set(word)
>>> my_set  # Sets aren’t ordered, so it will probably come back in a different order
{‘T’, ‘A’, ‘C’}
>>> len(my_set)
3
```

Huh, `3 != 4`, right? It looks like in taking the unique values in “CATT”, you had to throw one of them away because it was duplicated. Hey, convenient! So the short version is:

```
word = “CATT”
if len(word) != len(set(word)):
    print(word, “has duplicate letters”)
```

Oh, and because this might answer your next question:

If you have two sets `A` and `B`, `A <= B` is True if and only if every item in `A` is also in `B`. For example:

```
>>> {1,2,3} <= {1,2,3,4}
True
>>> {1,2,3,4} <= {1,2,3}
False
```

Well, that’s handy, because you can spell a word with a list of letters if and only if every letter in the word is also in the list of letters, right? And that looks a whole lot like the definition of `A <= B`! And indeed, it is:

```
>>> letters = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘t’]
>>> set('cat') <= set(letters)
True
>>> set('dog') <= set(letters)
False
```

Convenient, isn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

given:

```
lst = [ "A", "B" ,"C","T"]

word = "CAT"
```

there are many ways to accomplish this.

**compare lengths**

```
print(len([i for i in word if word.count(i.upper()) <= lst.count(i.upper())]) == len(word))
```

**all method**

```
print(all([word.count(i.upper()) <= lst.count(i.upper()) for i in word]))
```

**an expanded variation on the all method**

```
word = word.upper()

print(all([word.count(i) <= lst.count(i) for i in word]))
```

Comment: the list of letters randomly generates 10 letters. Sometimes you will have multiple letters so 2 Fs so you can make a word that contains 2 Fs, but how would I detect how many duplicate letters are there every time the list generates?

Comment: `detect how many duplicate letters` is very vague. that could mean the number of duplicates, the inclusive number of items that have a duplicate, or other things...

Comment: my apologies, I didn't realize I hadn't updated the operators after testing! Let me update with the working code

Comment: hopefully, that should be your solution

Comment: Yeah, it did thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to utilize `any()` function:

```
any([user_input.count(letter) > 1 for letter in your_list])
```

Would return `True` if any of the letters in `your_list` is repeated else `False`